# CakePHP: what are the table name and other restrictions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

What are the restrictions on table names and database design with CakePHP

i have a database already working another app.

I want to build a new interface with CakePHP

will i need to redesign the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to follow the naming conventions for the database with Cake. It makes things a lot easier and keeps things very organized and structured. However, any framework that forces you to follow ITS patterns should through red flags. At least it does for me.

That being said, the conventions are simple. Here are a few of the basics:

- Table names are pluralized (ie.
  users, computers, songs, teachers,
  children, etc.)
- Primary keys should be labeled as id
- The name field will be read
  automatically for display
- Foreign keys contain the singular
  name of the table _id (ie. user_id,
  computer_id, song_id, etc.)

http://book.cakephp.org/view/68/Creating-Database-Tables

These are just the basics. Now they may not apply to every application. Especially if you already have existing tables you want to use. It doesn't make sense to convert the structure of the database to have to fit in with Cake. So there are variables you can use in the model to tell cake the name of the tables and fields you are using.

To change the table name a model points to: `var $useTable = 'myTable';`

To tell cake what the display field is: `var $displayField = 'somefield';`

To tell cake what field to use as the PK: `var $primaryKey = 'some_id';`

http://book.cakephp.org/view/71/Model-Attributes

This should be enough to get you going. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Model and Database Conventions in CakePHP

http://book.cakephp.org/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions

Comment: In addition I would say that even though your database could have different structure and conventions you can build your cake interface without a problem.